# Program/Read 93LC46B with an Arduino with bit-banging

Tags: serial, eeprom

I'm Tom. I'm pretty new to electronics and programming but I've been getting better. So, recently I bought a 93lC46B EEPROM from Element 14 (It was $0.28! Why not!). I've been doing some research and reading the datasheet VERY carefully. But I still can't get the EEPROM to work right. I'm using an Arduino Uno to program the chip by using the Bit-Banging method. So what I've understood is that I need to cycle the clock, then pull the CS (Chip select) to high and then cycle the clock after each bit like this:

```
digitalWrite(CLK, LOW);
digitalWrite(DATAIN, VALUE);
digitalWrite(CLK, High);
```

But so far, that method hasn't been working right. I can't seem to read or write to the device properly. I'm using this set of bits to write 1 and 2 to the first address of the ROM: 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0.

Here's my code so far (Sorry in advance on how bad it is):

```
#define DATAOUT 11//Comes from DO on chip MISO
#define DATAIN 13 //Goes to DI on chip    MOSI
#define CLK 10
#define CS 9

int data[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int inst1[] = {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0};
int inst2[] = {1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600); //Start serial coms

  pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DATAOUT, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DATAIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(CLK, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW);

  //Write 12 to address 1
  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH); //Enable device
  //Write to memory
  for(int i=0;i<25;i++){
    Write(inst1[i]);
  }
  digitalWrite(CS, LOW); //Disable device
  delay(250); //TCSL Delay
  Serial.print("Memory sucessfully written\n");

  //Read memory
  digitalWrite(CS,HIGH); //Enable device
  for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
    Write(inst2[i]);
  }
  Serial.print("Read instruction written\n");
  for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
    saveBit(i);
  }
  for(int i=0;i<16;i++){
    Serial.print(data[i]+"\n");
  }
  digitalWrite(CS,LOW);
  delay(250);
  Serial.print("Read successful!\n");
}

void Write(int Bit){
  digitalWrite(CLK, LOW);
  if(Bit==0){
    digitalWrite(DATAIN, LOW);
  }
  if(Bit==1){
    digitalWrite(DATAIN, HIGH);
  }
  digitalWrite(CLK, HIGH);
  delay(1);
}

void saveBit(int outbit){
  digitalWrite(CLK, LOW);
  if(digitalRead(DATAOUT) == HIGH){
    data[outbit] = 1;
  }
  if(digitalRead(DATAOUT) == LOW){
    data[outbit] = 0;
  }
  digitalWrite(CLK, HIGH);
  delay(1);
}

void loop(){

}
```

Comment: Where have you connected your 93LC46's ORG pin?

Comment: @brhans This chip does not have an ORG pin. Read the data sheet before asking please.

Comment: Try access it with hardware SPI first. Mybe that can help.

Comment: I wanted the experience of running it with big-banging but I could try the SPI. I've found lots of posts for SPI.

Comment: Yet another improper migration from EESE.  The problem here is not with Arduino, but rather with lacking understanding of the peripheral's interface.  Send it back!